# How do I stop log interleaving from imported packages in Go?

Tags: go, logging, concurrency

I've created function 1 that is run concurrently using goroutines and waitgroups.

This function imports function 2 from another package, which has its own logging configuration.

If I use some techniques to stop log interleaving in function 1, like sync.Mutex or buffered log channel, this works.

But how can I stop the logs from the imported function 2 getting all mixed up?

Comment: You need a redesign of your logging capabilities. There's no magic in Go to silence logs from another package.

Comment: Thank you. I could change the logging config in the package I'm importing, that's true. But what if it was a 3rd party package I had no control over?

Comment: Then you'd either need to fork the library, or you'd be SOL.